# Modin df iterrows is painfully slow. Any alternative to speed it up?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, modin

I have a modin dataframe having ~120k rows. I want coalesce some columns of it. Modin df iterrows is taking lot of time, so I tried with numpy.where. Numpy.where is on the equivalent pandas df does it in 5-10 minutes but same thing on modin df takes ~30 minutes. Any alternative to speed this task for modin dataframe?

[cols_to_be_coalesced] --> this list contains list of columns to be coalesced. It contains 10-15 columns.

Code:

```
for COL in [cols_to_be_coalesced]:
    df['COL'] = np.where(df['COL']!='', df['COL'], df['COL_X'])
```

If df is pandas dataframe, it executes in ~10 minutes, but if its a modin dataframe, it takes ~30 minutes. So is there a any equivalent code for numpy.where for modin dataframes to speed up this operation?

Comment: Try with - np.where(df['COL'] .values!='', df['COL'] .values, df['COL_X'] .values)

Comment: @Nk03
I tried with your suggestion, but it didn't make any difference, it took 1 hour to do it. 
numpy-pandas does it in 4 minutes.

Comment: what's the length of [cols_to_be_coalesced]. If it's large, then you should consider vectorizing it.

Comment: @Nk03 - 
The list contains 15-20 columns. 
Let me explain - I'm merging 5 datasets one by one. After EACH merge this above operation happens. Total records after 5 merges is ~120k. So after each merge, around 15 to 20 columns needs to coalesced using above code. Numpy-pandas takes just 5 minutes. But with modin, its taking 50 minutes. 
Can you please show me how to vectorize it for modin ?

Comment: So, that means for loop is running for 15-20 iterations?. If you use multithreading/ multiprocessing then you can speed up this for loop by 15 times approx.

Comment: @Nk03 - For loop really is not the problem because with this for loop numpy-pandas with np.where completes it in 5 minutes. np.where doesn't work for modin df as expected. I need np.where eqvivalent function for modin which will do this in similar time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your `np.where` is slow because `np.where` converts the Modin dataframe to a numpy array, and converting Modin dataframes to numpy is [slow](https://github.com/modin-project/modin/issues/1926). Is this version using `pandas.Series.where` (not the Modin `where` implementation, because that hasn't been added yet) faster for you?

```py
for COL in [cols_to_be_coalesced]:
    df['COL'] = df['COL'].where(df['COL'] != '', df['COL_X'])
```

I find that that approach takes 1.58 seconds versus 70 seconds for the original approach in this example:

```py
import modin.pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(2**20, 2**8))).add_prefix("col")
# setting column with np.where takes 70 seconds
df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] % 2 == 0, df['col1'], df['col2'])
# setting column with pandas.Series.where takes 1.58 seconds
df['col1'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'] % 2 == 0, df['col2'])
```